# Make Coroutine wait for Jsoup response in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup, kotlin-coroutines

I'm kind of new developing with Android, and have problems understanding how things works. I made an app to **scrape** content from a page, and download elements, first with AsyncTask and worked, but since AsyncTask doesn't let me communicate with the UI Activity on progress, i decided to change to coroutines, checked an example, and the same code i used doesn't seems to work.

I used a few logs to try to determine the problem, and seems like it doesn't wait for the Jsoup request. The coroutine first calls a method `scrapePage()` to download the HTML and **scrape** the links, and then calls `downloadImages()` to add the links to Android's DownloadManager. In the logs `Log.d("action", "Start Scraping")` is printed, but `Log.d("action", "Page downloaded")` doesn't, still we get `Log.d("action", "End")` from the coroutine, which makes me think that instead of waiting for the Jsoup request to answer, it goes with an empty response, causing the rest of the code to not work correctly.

DownloadService.kt

```
object DownloadService {

    private val parentJob = Job()
    
    ...

    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + parentJob +
            coroutineExceptionHandler)

    fun StartService(URL: String, location:String, contx:Context) {

        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Log.d("action", "Start")
            val links = scrapePage(URL)
            val download = downloadImages(links, location, contx)
            Log.d("action", "End")
        }
    }

    private suspend fun scrapePage(url: String): MainActivity.Scraped =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            var URL = url
            var scrape = MainActivity.Scraped()
            try {
                Log.d("action", "Start Scraping")
                var response = Jsoup.connect(URL).get()
                Log.d("action", "Page downloaded")
                response.getElementsByClass("link").forEach {
                    /*Scrape URLs*/
                    Log.d("action", "Add "+link)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                when(e) {
                    is HttpStatusException -> {
                        System.out.println(e.getStatusCode())
                        scrape.error = true
                        error = true
                    }
                }
            }
            return@withContext scrape
        }

    ...
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...
    fun makeRequest(URL : String) {
        WorkingURL = URL
        var uri = ""
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            uri = MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString()
            log.text = uri
        } else {
            uri = getStoragePath()
            log.text = uri
        }
        DownloadService.StartService(URL, uri, this)
        Log.d("links", DownloadService.getError().toString())
    }
}
```

I am not sure where the problem is, nor where to start searching. I know the code for the **Scraping** works, because i used it before with AsyncTask, so the problem seems to be passing it to coroutines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `Jsoup.connect(URL).get()` is throwing an error. so, `Log.d("action", "Page downloaded")` is not called.

But since you are handling the exception, the code runs the catch part and completes the suspend function and moves on to `downloadImages()`.

---

**Solution**

First, add a log in the catch part of `scrapePage()` function and find out what is causing the exception. Everything else in your code is good.

Comment: Was my thought also, but is not the case, at least not if i'm using correctly the Debug: In the catch i make scrap.error = true which i use later to know if the request failed or not, setted an stop at a log between scrapPage() and downloadImages(), checked the variable links, and error was false, meaning that it never passed for the catch, or at least that's what i think it happened.

Comment: for your `scrap.error` to be updated properly add `else` condition in your `when`

Comment: Sorry to answer late, i was away and couldn't check it. Yes, it was the reason, seems like for some reason i'm still checking, my code doesn't seems to be sending the url, but instead an empty string, reason as to why the request fails. Thanks for your help!